# Wifi on Android SDK

Tags: android-2.2-froyo

I have installed the Android SDK and I noticed that the WiFi button is not enabled in the emulator. I want to know, whether this functionality available on Emulator or not, and why. I have been looking for a convincing answer for a long period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no WiFi chip inside emulator, so the button cannot be pressed.

Emulator already has a network connection routed through your host PC, so WiFi is not really needed.

Comment: I have one last question, so if we want to work on an application that needs a wifi configuration , we need an android mobile phone in addition to the emulator?

Comment: Yes, you'll need a real phone.